# Standard for adding multiple values of a single HTTP Header to a request or response

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, http-headers

If I want to add a list of values as an HTTP Header, is there a standard way to do this?  I couldn't find anything (that I could easily understand) in RFC 822.  For example, is
comma separated values standard or semi-colon separated values.  Is there a standard at all?

Example:

```
Key: value1;value2;value3
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the HTTP spec [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) where it says:

> Multiple message-header fields with
>   the same field-name MAY be present in
>   a message if and only if the entire
>   field-value for that header field is
>   defined as a comma-separated list
>   [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible
>   to combine the multiple header fields
>   into one "field-name: field-value"
>   pair, without changing the semantics
>   of the message, by appending each
>   subsequent field-value to the first,
>   each separated by a comma. The order
>   in which header fields with the same
>   field-name are received is therefore
>   significant to the interpretation of
>   the combined field value, and thus a
>   proxy MUST NOT change the order of
>   these field values when a message is
>   forwarded.

What this means is that you can send the same header multiple times in a response with different values, as long as those values can be appended to each other using a comma.  This also means that you can send multiple values in a single header by concatenating them with commas.

So in your case it will be:

```
Key: value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: you can send the same header multiple times in a response with different values *if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list*. I think this refers to the fact that not all headers are allowed to be a set of values. For example, the Content-Length must be a single value.

Comment: @marc-novakowski - i also wish to have few words in this thema :) - no't down voting but leaving you with the feeling that im "unsatisfied"

Comment: What if two conflicting values are sent in the same header. For example: "X-Frame-Options: DENY, SAMEORIGIN". How should browser process it? Get the last one?

Comment: The RFC you linked leads to a page with an error. I found the related section on the new document here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-5.2

Answer (score 20):

by all means @marc-novakowski you narrowing the "problem" :)

> normally (per HTTP spec) we delimit each value from the other using a comma ','

**but we will examine a simple case:**

```
Cookie-set: language=pl; expires=Sat, 15-Jul-2017 23:58:22 GMT; path=/; domain=x.com   
Cookie-set: id=123 expires=Sat, 15-Jul-2017 23:58:22 GMT; path=/; domain=x.com; httponly
```

*how do you join such headers when the values one from another are delimited with commas - case when coma can appear ???*

then the "client" responsibility is to **choose** and decide the **strategy** eg **drop, merg** (if merg how)?

pleas take look at Mozilla implementation of **nsHttpHeaderArray**

https://github.com/bnoordhuis/mozilla-central/blob/master/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpHeaderArray.h#L185

> mozilla choose to **use a newline delimiter '\n'** in this case (for certain header fields names)

I encourage when you face a such situation to search in common existing solutions - as they providing familiar scheme

**flags explanations:**

> Cookies are no part of the HTTP standard. Cookies are defined in an
> own RFC, 6265 (formally 2965 and 2109). Even the HTTP 2 RFC only
> mentions cookies but does not define them as part of the standard. –
> @mecki Aug 25 at 18:56

please look one more time for sentence:

per HTTP spec we delimit each value from other using a comma ',' - there is no word cookie here :)

maybe we need to precise we talk here about HEADER FIELD(s - when repeating them) **"Cookie-set" is a header field** and it has value .. those value we consider to be a "COOKIE/S" - thus client/server implementation should handle such "COOKIE/S"

SEE VALUES OR NAME PAIRS :) IN HTTP 1/1 SPEC

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2

Comment: Cookies are no part of the HTTP standard. Cookies are defined in an own RFC, 6265 (formally 2965 and 2109). Even the HTTP 2 RFC only mentions cookies but does not define them as part of the standard.

Answer (score 9):

However not all values with the same field name may be combined into field values list. For example, in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) we may read

> Note: In practice, the "Set-Cookie" header field ([RFC6265]) often
> appears multiple times in a response message and does not use the
> list syntax, violating the above requirements on multiple header
> fields with the same name.  Since it cannot be combined into a
> single field-value, recipients ought to handle "Set-Cookie" as a
> special case while processing header fields.  (See Appendix A.2.3
> of [Kri2001] for details.)