# Parsing cookies

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies

I have a self-hosted WCF service with an endpoint set up with WebHttpBinding listening for HTTP requests. I need to access cookies passed with these requests. I can get the `Cookie:` header value, but I am stuck with actual parsing. My implementation attempt was using `CookieContainer`:

```
var container = new CookieContainer();
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/");
container.SetCookies(uri, cookieHeader);
var cookies = container.GetCookies(uri).OfType<Cookie>();
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
}
```

Issue with this code is that `CookieContainer` expects cookies to be separated by comma (`cookieHeader="c1=v1,c2=v2"`), while browsers tend to use semicolon (`cookieHeader="c1=v1;c2=v2"`) for that. Since [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.2.1) permits only semicolon to be used as separator (older RFC's permit both, though) I am a bit puzzled why `CookieContainer` only supports comma. Now I am struggling for finding an alternative solution for the problem that seems to be quite typical. How do I parse cookies properly? ASP.NET should be able to do it, does it expose any publicly usable classes for that?

Answer (score 15):

#### Why does it not work?

As I understand it, the separators vary for a `Set-Cookie:` and the `Cookie:` headers.  `Set-Cookie:` is normally duplicated if multiple headers exist, whereas `Cookie:` has multiple cookies in a single header.  From [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3.1):

```
== Server -> User Agent ==

Set-Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Path=/; Domain=example.com

== User Agent -> Server ==

Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; lang=en-US
```

The `Set-Cookie:` header [can be combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096888/standard-for-adding-multiple-values-of-a-single-http-header-to-a-request-or-resp) into a single string by appending each header separated by a comma:

```
Set-Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly,lang=en-US; Path=/; Domain=example.com
```

`CookieContainer` is designed to be used on the client side (by a user-agent), so the `SetCookies(Uri, string)` method only parses the syntax used by `Set-Cookie:`.

#### How does ASP.Net do it

ASP.Net uses an internal method to parse the `Cookie:` header, and it does not appear to be exposed by any public methods.  See [`HttpListenerRequest.Cookies`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListenerRequest.cs,670):

```
private CookieCollection ParseCookies(Uri uri, string setCookieHeader) {
    GlobalLog.Print("HttpListenerRequest#" + ValidationHelper.HashString(this) + "::ParseCookies() uri:" + uri + " setCookieHeader:" + setCookieHeader);
    CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
    CookieParser parser = new CookieParser(setCookieHeader);
    for (;;) {
        Cookie cookie = parser.GetServer();
        GlobalLog.Print("HttpListenerRequest#" + ValidationHelper.HashString(this) + "::ParseCookies() CookieParser returned cookie:" + ValidationHelper.ToString(cookie));
        if (cookie==null) {
            // EOF, done.
            break;
        }
        if (cookie.Name.Length==0) {
            continue;
        }
        cookies.InternalAdd(cookie, true);
    }
    return cookies;
}
```

#### How can I parse the header, then?

Nancy has a [very concise parser](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/97b40c6c4557d4c17caef827eced9fecb5550b37/src/Nancy/Request.cs#L173) that could be used if licensing permits:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> GetCookieData()
{
    var cookieDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (!this.Headers.Cookie.Any())
    {
        return cookieDictionary;
    }

    var values = this.Headers["cookie"].First().TrimEnd(';').Split(';');
    foreach (var parts in values.Select(c => c.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)))
    {
        var cookieName = parts[0].Trim();
        string cookieValue;

        if (parts.Length == 1)
        {
            //Cookie attribute
            cookieValue = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            cookieValue = parts[1];
        }

        cookieDictionary[cookieName] = cookieValue;
    }

    return cookieDictionary;
}
```