# Jersey2 - Multivalue response headers are not comma separated

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

For a REST service, I'm adding multiple values to a header and the client expects the values to be comma separated in the response header:

```
test-header: value1, value2
```

I have implemented this in a `ContainerResponseFilter` like this:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        String headerOfInterest = "test-header";
        List<String> header = responseContext.getStringHeaders().get(headerOfInterest);
        if (header == null) {
            responseContext.getHeaders().addAll(headerOfInterest, "value1", "value2");
        }
    }
```

However this seems to add the headers twice, instead of comma separating the values.

```
...
test-header: value1
test-header: value2
...
```

I have tried using `responseContext.getHeaders().add()` twice and adding each value, but whichever way I add the values, they end up showing two times in the response instead of being comma separated.

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097052/10789057), to me it seems comma separated multi value is the standard. So how do I achive this in Jersey?

Jersey version: 2.29
Tomcat version: 9.5