# How to Set the value of HTTPHeaders as Array using org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on the springboot application where I need to add a header to request API where they used *org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders* to set the Header values to the request.

I can see they used below code for setting the string value header.

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("correlationId", "12232324545x32321");
```

My requirement is to add a header named `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` and it expect the value as an array:

```
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey = ["file1"]
```

How can set the above using using the `HttpHeaders`. I refer the below the Javadocs. I could not able to figure out the right way to do.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097052/8668332
You should either add the header multiple times or concatenate the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers are just name-value pairs (as strings). Consequently, you can just set this array in the required representation as the value. Don't forget to escape `"` properly.

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("correlationId", "12232324545x32321");
headers.set("x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey", "[\"file1\"]");

System.out.println(headers);
```

```
[correlationId:"12232324545x32321", x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey:"["file1"]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write `[` and `]` explicte in the value

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey", "[\"file1\"]");
```