# how get access to two request header parameters with same name in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, http, header

How can I get value of two request header parameters with same name in `laravel`?
in Postman I called a specific route of application and set header parameter named `msg` two times with two different values. but in laravel controller, when I use `$request->header("msg")` it gives me just first `msg` header!
how is it possible two access to both headers named `msg`?

picture:

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5cUN.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkdEd.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can send the same header twice with different values. Maybe you have to do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096888/standard-for-adding-multiple-values-of-a-single-http-header-to-a-request-or-resp

Comment: I don’t know Laravel too well, but I do know that they use parts of Symfony, so maybe this is applicable. The [`getHeader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/14c45f43b6a00e69efbe74df8dd1a02a970f7ada/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Response.php#L89) method returns an array if false is passed as the second argument. Maybe something similar is in Laravel?

Comment: @shaedrich Thanks for your recommendation, but I need to define two different header param with same name.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, Thank you for your help, unfortunately there is not such a function in laravel as I know.