# Multiple cache-control headers in response

Tags: java, spring

I am not so good in Java + Spring, but I'd like to add Cache-Control header to my ResponseEntity.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/{id}", method = GET")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    try {
            ...
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setCacheControl("max-age=600, public");

            return new ResponseEntity<String>(body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

I added two lines of code for HttpHeaders and now I get two Cache-Control headers in my response:

one with public and another with private. why?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097052/9068895

Comment: @Alex my question is why am getting two cache-control headers, even if i added only one

Comment: Doesn't look like spring logic until you have some special global handlers. Checked in our environment and single header is returned in curl, Safari, Chrome

Comment: Does this appear in your local testing environment or on a "real" server? An intermediate proxy server or container configuration etc. could add a header to the request without checking that you already have one set for Cache-Control.