# When are HTTP header values comma or semi-colon separated?

Tags: http

There are inconsistencies in the way multiple HTTP header values are separated in the [Mdn Web Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

For example, [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) the value syntax is comma delimited shown below:

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: <method>, <method>, …`

But, [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) is semi-colon separated like shown below:

`Content-Security-Policy: <policy-directive>; <policy-directive>`

Why are the two inconsistent?

I was expecting everything to be comma-separated as per [this answer in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097052/17985195).

Comment: @KlausD both of those sentences are technically incorrect. I elaborated a bit in my answer. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: it depends on the specification of the specific header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, with 1 specific exception, the following 2 are equivalent:

```
Header: foo
Header: bar
```

And:

```
Header: foo, bar
```

So these two are also the same:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

and

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
```

Any non-broken HTTP client will handle them identically.

So when you see unquoted commas, you can think of them as 2 distinct header values.

The `;` is typically used to indicate that a set of parameters for a value is following. For example, in this example there are 2 values, each have a `q` parameter:

```
Accept: text/html; q=0.5, text/plain; q=0.2
```

Which again is equivalent to:

```
Accept: text/html; q=0.5
Accept: text/plain; q=0.2
```

The one exception is `Set-Cookie`, which incorrectly uses `,`. This was a *mistake* but is part of the HTTP specification.

Note that aside from the comma, there's not a lot of generalization in terms of how HTTP headers are encoded, so you need to look up the specific header in the specific relevant spec in order to find out how to decode it.

New HTTP headers will likely follow a specific format though: Structured Fields: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8941.html

But for any older header it's a bit more of a free for all with a few general rules and guidelines. Comma is dependable as a value separator though aside from that one exception. `;` is *usually* a parameter separator. In the structured fields spec `;` is *always* a parameter separator.

In your example `Content-Security-Policy` chose a `;` as a value separator, so this breaks the 'usually a parameter separator'-rule. But according to the spec multiple `Content-Security-Policy` may appear so you can expect both `,` and `;`. Perhaps they also provide some guidelines how these directives are merged if they appear as multiple values.

Comment: This question was generalized to help everyone but for context, this was for an ASP.NET core application and it was causing key conflict errors when adding `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST` separately. So my only option was to go `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST` which is where the comma vs semi colon separator confusion came. But thank you for the response

Comment: @TP95 Not familiar with ASP, but I know some frameworks just force you to set multi-value headers as an array instead of one at a time. Others have a `set()` and separate `append()`. Glad you figured it out though